# gopkg.in/ini.v1 cannot handle duplicate keys in same section

Tags: go

Using code like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "gopkg.in/ini.v1"
)

func main() {
    cfg, err := ini.LoadSources(ini.LoadOptions{AllowShadows: true}, "test.ini")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Fail to read file: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    for _, section := range cfg.Sections() {
       for _, key := range section.Keys() {
          fmt.Printf("section[%s], key=[%s], value=[%s]\n", section.Name(), key.Name(), key.Value())
        }       
   }
}
```

With an INI file like this:

```
[test]
        Key1=Key1Value1
        Key1=Key1Value2
        Key2=Key2Value1
        Key2=Key2Value2
```

I get this output:

```
section[test], key=[Key1], value=[Key1Value1]
section[test], key=[Key2], value=[Key2Value1]
```

I would LIKE to get this output:

```
section[test], key=[Key1], value=[Key1Value1]
section[test], key=[Key1], value=[Key1Value2]
section[test], key=[Key2], value=[Key2Value1]
section[test], key=[Key2], value=[Key2Value2]
```

(And no, I can't change from INI file format as I'm trying to duplicate behavior translating from another language)

Answer (score 0):

Should you be using [Key.ValueWithShadows](https://gowalker.org/github.com/go-ini/ini#Key_ValueWithShadows)?

E.g. this modified code will give you the desired output for your `test.ini`:

```
func main() {
    cfg, err := ini.LoadSources(ini.LoadOptions{AllowShadows: true}, "test.ini")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Fail to read file: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    for _, section := range cfg.Sections() {
        for _, key := range section.Keys() {
            for _, v := range key.ValueWithShadows() {
                fmt.Printf("section[%s], key=[%s], value=[%s]\n", section.Name(), key.Name(), v)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eli, that worked great!   I asked the author to add documentation